# Why BoundService is null?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm really new at Android and try to create simple service. I checked an tried to [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services#kotlin)

but i cannot start service. Service always null.Program is not calling `boundServiceConnection` function

Here my code Service code

```
class BoundService : Service() {
  private val localBinder: IBinder = MyBinder()
  override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
      return localBinder
  }

  fun randomGenerator(): Int {
      val randomNumber = Random()
      return randomNumber.nextInt()
  }

  inner class MyBinder : Binder() {
      fun getService(): BoundService = this@BoundService
  }
}
```

Here is my main activity

```
var boundService: BoundService? = null
var isBound = false
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    Intent(this, BoundService::class.java).also { intent ->
        bindService(intent, boundServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
    }
}

fun onButtonClick(v: View) {
    if (isBound) {
        val num: Int = boundService!!.randomGenerator()
        Toast.makeText(this, "number: $num", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}

override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    if (isBound) {
        unbindService(boundServiceConnection)
        isBound = false
    }
}

private val boundServiceConnection: ServiceConnection = object : ServiceConnection {
    override fun onServiceConnected(name: ComponentName, service: IBinder) {
        val binderBridge = service as MyBinder
        boundService = binderBridge.getService()
        isBound = true
    }

    override fun onServiceDisconnected(name: ComponentName) {
        isBound = false
        boundService = null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regard to the service component of your app, it should be registered in your application manifest.

The [android guide on bound services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services#kotlin) seems to not provide any information on the required (and assumed missing) manifest entry as it was covered in the [service overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#Declaring).

Comment: You are right! I missed that part. Thank you so much